# Passing JavaScript-obtained variables to modal popup textBox in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

How can I pass a variable obtained through JavaScript to a textbox on a modal popup? I've tried using a hidden field and even a textbox on the parent page, inside or outside an update panel, but when I click on the link button that opens the modal popup, their values are reset to default. Despite trying various approaches, I can't seem to succeed.

I have a table in a repeater, and I need to determine the cells selected by the user: the start and ending cell of the selection. I achieve this with the provided JavaScript code. When the user selects one or more cells, I have the start/end values stored in two  elements with runat="server" attributes. This is the javascript function:

```
$(function () {
            var mouse_down = false;
            var row, col;    // starting row and column
            var $tr;

            $("#tblPersonale td")
                .mousedown(function () {
                    $("#col_to").html('?');
                    mouse_down = true;

                    // clear last selection for a fresh start
                    $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted");
                    $(this).addClass("highlighted");

                    $tr = $(this).parent();
                    row = $tr.parent().find("tr").index($(this).parent());
                    col = $tr.find("td").index($(this));

                    $("#row").html(row);
                    $("#col_fr").html(col - 1);
                   
                    

                    return false; // prevent text selection
                })

                .mouseover(function () {
                    if (mouse_down) {
                        $("#col_to").html('?');
                        if ($tr[0] === $(this).parent()[0]) {
                            var col2 = $(this).parent().find("td").index($(this)); // current column
                            var col1 = col;
                            if (col > col2) { col1 = col2; col2 = col; }

                            $("#col_fr").html(col1-1);
                            $("#col_to").html(col2 - 1);
                            
                            // clear all selection to avoid extra cells selected
                            $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted");

                            // then select cells from col to col2
                            for (var i = col1; i <= col2; i++) {
                                if (col1>1){
                                    $tr[0].cells[i].className = "highlighted";}
                            }
                        }

                    }
                })
                .bind("selectstart", function () {
                    return false; // prevent text selction in IE
                })

            $(document)
                .mouseup(function () {
                    mouse_down = false;
                });
        });
```

So, when user selects one or more cells I have the start/end value in here:

```
<span id="col_fr" runat="server" enableviewstate="true">?</span>
<span id="col_to" runat="server" enableviewstate="true">?</span>
```

The link button I'm using to trigger the modal popup is as follows:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkAddDip"  OnClick="lnkAddDip_Click">
```

I need assistance in ensuring that when the link button is clicked, the values obtained by JavaScript are preserved and can be utilized to populate a textbox within the modal popup. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some detail or external reference for this approach? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did what I want by tuning the original javascript function.
I added 3 hiddenfield on the page and then I add this bit

```
var hdncol_fr = document.getElementById("hdncol_fr").value;
var hdncol_to = document.getElementById("hdncol_to").value;
var hdnrow = document.getElementById("hdnrow").value;
if (hdncol_fr = '?'){
   document.getElementById("hdncol_fr").value = col - 1;
   document.getElementById("hdncol_to").value = col2 - 1;
   document.getElementById("hdnrow").value = row;
}
```

This way the hidden fields values are set only when user actively select some cells, when there is a postback event the javascript function returns '?' for the 3 values, so with the added code the hidden field maintains the previous values until user select something else.

Answer (score 0):

It just have to move the parameter code o a javascript function like

```
function getURL(){
   var param1 = someField.value/*get field value*/;
   var url= "Home.aspx?col_fr="+ param1;
   window.location= url;
  return false;
}
```

**Html**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkAddDip"  OnClick="lnkAddDip_Click" OnClientClick="getURL()">
```

Comment: I understood that I didn't go anywhere with my previous question, so I updated it with the real goal. Please check the updated question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't use UpdatePanel or Modal popup server side. You can use a Thickbox or similar jquery plugin to open the popoup.

Popup can be an inpage div or another page. In case of page, you can easily pass parameters in the url, in case of inpage div, you can get hidden field values.

You can find jquery overlay as Thickbox: just add css and js to your site, the right class on the link and fix the url to open.

**Solution using another page**

Imagine to use Colorbox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/):

**PRE**

Suppose you have your variable values in some hidden field in your page

**TODO**

1. include jquery in your page
2. Download and include css and js for colorbox
3. In your page add a html tag with on click event
4. Add a script section in your page

   ```
   function openLink()
   {       
       var hiddenValue= $("#col_fr").text(); // or .html()    
       var urlToOpen = "yourpage.aspx?ids=" + hiddenValue;    
       $.colorbox({
               iframe: true,    
               width: "75%",    
               height: "75%",    
               href: urlToOpen
      });
   }
   ```

Then in Yourpage.aspx you can use url parameter "ids".

Code is not tested!

Comment: Some detail or external reference for this approach? Thank you

Comment: Have you already find on Google an overlay plugin as thickbox?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking how to use it in asp.net but for now it's a no-go. I'm not a javascript expert and I always struggle to work with jquery. In fact for this reason I usually don't. That's why I was looking for a non-jquery solution.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness but I can't do what I want with it. I show the thickbox but then I can't get parameters from the parent. I have to change approach.

Comment: If you show thickbox, it's the first step... you told you are not a js expert :D
Where do you store parameters to pass to thickbox?

Comment: they are stored into span called col_fr and col_to by javascript executed when user select cells of the table (the javascript is the one in the first post). But I think I will use an external webform opened in a new window to simulate the modal popup and that's it. Much more simpler and clean.

Comment: I edited my post. Why not try... Overlay is better then popup